# How to send strings from an Peer-To-Peer server to a client using Unity C#?

Tags: c#

I´m programming a game with the Unity engine using C#. I want users to function as servers or clients and also I want the server to be able to send messages(strings) to the clients. I´ve tried using functions, but of course it didn´t realy work since if have 2 seperate identities. Right now I´m trying to use RCP but it doesn´t seem to work like in the tutorial....I get an compiler error in the Update function. I´ve attached the Network View component.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
private int maxConnections = 12;
private int serverPort = 9955;
public string message = "NoMessageSelected";
public bool sendMessage = false;

public void OnGUI()
{
    //Creates 2 Buttons on GUI, if disconnected
    if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected) 
    {
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 100, 100, 30), "Server")) 
        {
            Network.InitializeServer (maxConnections, serverPort);
        }
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (200, 100, 100, 30), "Client")) 
        {
            Network.Connect ("localHost", serverPort);
        }
    }
    ////Shows Client or Server GUI
    //Client
    if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Client) 
    {
        GUI.Label (new Rect (100, 100, 400, 30), "Connected to Server");
        //Disconnect
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (200, 200, 100, 30), "Disconnect"))
        {
            Network.Disconnect();
            MasterServer.UnregisterHost();
        }
    }
    //Server
    if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Server) 
    {
        GUI.Label (new Rect (100, 100, 400, 30), "Clients connected: " +
        Network.connections.Length);
        message = GUI.TextField(new Rect(150, 150, 200, 20), message, 25);//How to 
        receive "message"?
        //Sends message via RPC
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (200, 200, 100, 30), "Send Message"))
        {
            networkView.RPC ("PrintText", RPCMode.All, "Hello world");
        }
    }
}


  public void Update()
  {
      Debug.Log (message);
  }

  @RPC
  function PrintText (text : String)
  {
      Debug.Log(text);
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that.  Error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `PrintText' in class, struct, or interface member declaration. Well, I doubt it´s wrong since i copied it from the Unity manual http://docs.unity3d.ru/Components/net-RPCDetails.html... so I´m a little confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've copied JS functon declaration into C# script. You can see examples in all three languages here - http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NetworkView.RPC.html

C# equivalent:

```
[RPC]
public void PrintText (String text)
{
    Debug.Log(text);
}
```

Comment: Was it helpful? Did you manage to fix compiler error and pass your string via RPC?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, back then i`ve been realy new to stack overflow and I didn`t know how to ask proper questions and answer them. As far as I remember Max K. 's solution solved the main problem. That doesn't actually mean the code stated above is good.